# what is the meaning of FOUND in grep FOUND

Tags: command-line, scripts

I came across this command 
`sudo clamscan -v -r /folder/to/scan/ | grep FOUND >> /path/to/save/report/file.txt`

while studying clam ( an open source antivirus engine). 
I am unable to understand the meaning of the argument FOUND passed to grep. I tried man grep but it does not give information on such an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` is a line matching tool , similar to `findstr` in Windows , except more powerful. What you see in your example is this structure:

```
command | grep SOMEWORD >> file.txt
```

The basic idea there is that we run `command` it's output will be given to `grep` for searching `SOMEWORD` and the resulting output will be only those line that contain the word `FOUND`.  Because we have input to `grep` coming from another command via pipe `|` , we don't need double quotes, but otherwise typical grep command would look like this: `grep "USERNAME" /etc/passwd`

As for `>>` I believe that's unnecessary if we're generating a new report , because `>>` will append text to file, but in case of `>` file will be overwritten each time. What I think that `>>` does is sort of create a log of all scans.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, `grep` is used to display only strings containing a specified keyword, instead of displaying the entire output of a file or command in the terminal.

From my understanding, `sudo clamscan -v -r /folder/to/scan/ | grep FOUND >> /path/to/save/report/file.txt` will read the scan file of ClamAV (it needs to specified), find any line in it that contains the word "FOUND" and will copy these lines into a new file (that you specify).

It's not so much an argument as the thing you are asking `grep` to find in the specified file.

Answer (score 2):

"grep FOUND" will filter only lines that contain the word "FOUND" from the output of the "clamscan" command.

It's not an option for grep, its the actual data that grep is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo clamscan -v -r /folder/to/scan/
```

will return results and those results are fed ("piped") to "grep".

If in the results is the word "FOUND" it is added to the text file "/path/to/save/report/file.txt". The ">>" means to append to the file.